# Bishop game - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, chess

> A bishop can capture any other bishop if it lies along the same
>   diagonal line, so long as no other bishop is in its path.
>   Given a list of coordinates of the bishops locations, and a board size, determine how many bishops are unsafe.

This code has a time complexity of \$O(N*K)\$ where N is the number of bishops, K is (N- current index).

Is there a way to improve this?

```
bishops = [(0, 0),
           (1, 1),
           (0, 2),
           (1, 3),
           (2, 0),
           (2, 2)]
size = 5

moves = [(1, 1), (1, -1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1)]

captured = []
for index, coordinates in enumerate(bishops):
    remaining = bishops[index + 1:]
    seen = bishops[:index + 1]
    for dx, dy in moves:
        x, y = coordinates
        while 0 <= x + dx < size and 0 <= y + dy < size:
            x += dx
            y += dy
            if (x, y) in seen:
                break
            if (x, y) in remaining:
                remaining.remove((x, y))
                capture = f"{coordinates} takes {x, y}"
                captured.append(capture)
                break

print(f"There are {len(captured)} moves")
print(*captured, sep = "\n")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If bishop `X`, `Y` & `Z` are all on a diagonal, `X` can capture `Y`, `Y` can capture both `X` & `Z`, and `Z` can capture `Y`.  All 3 are unsafe.  If the problem has *no requirement to determine exactly which bishop captures which bishops* -- just determine the number which could be captured -- then you don't need to move each bishop along the each of the four `dx, dy in moves` directions until it encounters another bishop.  That is just mechanical busy work.

A bishop `X` is unsafe if any other bishop `Y` satisfies either (or both) of the following:

- `bishop[X][0] + bishop[X][1] == bishop[Y][0] + bishop[Y][1]`, or
- `bishop[X][0] - bishop[X][1] == bishop[Y][0] - bishop[Y][1]`.

You can partition the bishops according to diagonals.  If two or more bishops are on the same diagonal, all of those bishops are unsafe.

Note that the `size` of the board is unnecessary.

---

The following is a review of and improvement upon [@RootTwo's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/224052/100620).

A vanilla dictionary is a poor choice for `nwse` and `nesw`.  That requires you check if the diagonal index has already been created in the dictionary, to determine whether to store a new list in the dictionary, or to appended to the existing list.  A better option is to use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict), which automatically creates the entry using the provided default if that entry is not present:

```
from collections import defaultdict

nwse = defaultdict(list)
nesw = defaultdict(list)
```

The `bishops` is already a collection of `tuple` coordinates.  Creating your own tuples in `= [(row,col)]` and `.append((row,col))` is creating new objects identical to the existing ones in everything except identity.  There is no need to pollute the memory with these new tuples; just reuse the existing ones:

```
for bishop in bishops:
    row, col = bishop
    nwse[row + col].append(bishop)
    nesw[row - col].append(bishop)
```

The `for k,v in nwse.items():` loop never uses the dictionary key value (`k`) in the body of the loop.  It makes no sense to extract it from the dictionary.  Just loop over the `values()` of the dictionaries:

```
in_danger = set()

for v in nwse.values():
    if len(v) > 1:
        in_danger.update(v)

for v in nesw.values():
    if len(v) > 1:
        in_danger.update(v)
```

The problem asks for "how many bishops are unsafe", not the number that are safe.  So the output should be:

```
print(len(in_danger))
```

Finally, follow the PEP-8 standards.  Specifically, you need a space after all of your commas.

```
from collections import defaultdict

bishops = [(0, 0),
           (1, 1),
           (0, 2),
           (1, 3),
           (2, 0),
           (2, 2)]

nwse = defaultdict(list)
nesw = defaultdict(list)

for bishop in bishops:
    row, col = bishop
    nwse[row + col].append(bishop)
    nesw[row - col].append(bishop)

in_danger = set()

for v in nwse.values():
    if len(v) > 1:
        in_danger.update(v)

for v in nesw.values():
    if len(v) > 1:
        in_danger.update(v)

print(len(in_danger))
```

Answer (score 7):

### O(n)

You can transform the (row,column) coordinate of a bishop to a (row+column, row-column) coordinate. The row+column coordinate tells you which upper-left to lower right diagonal the bishop is on.  The row-column coordinate tells you which upper-right to lower-left diagonal the bishop is on.

```
      row + col                     row - col
7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14       7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13       6  5  4  3  2  1  0 -1
5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12       5  4  3  2  1  0 -1 -2
4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11       4  3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3
3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10       3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4
2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9       2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8       1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7       0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7
```

Now create two dictionaries.  One that maps each row+col value to a list of bishops on that diagonal.  The other one similarly maps the row-col value.  Any dict entry with more than one bishop, means all of those bishops are in danger.

```
bishops = [(0, 0),
           (1, 1),
           (0, 2),
           (1, 3),
           (2, 0),
           (2, 2)]

nwse = {}
nesw = {}

for row,col in bishops:
    nwse_index = row + col
    if nwse_index not in nwse:
        nwse[nwse_index] = [(row,col)]
    else:
        nwse[nwse_index].append((row,col))

    nesw_index = row - col
    if nesw_index not in nesw:
        nesw[nesw_index] = [(row,col)]
    else:
        nesw[nesw_index].append((row,col))

in_danger = set()

for k,v in nwse.items():
    if len(v) > 1:
        in_danger.update(v)

for k,v in nesw.items():
    if len(v) > 1:
        in_danger.update(v)

safe_bishops = set(bishops) - in_danger

print(len(safe_bishops))
```

### Improved code

based on AJNeuman's answer and my comment below.

The row - col index is offset by adding -8 so that all the values will be < 0.
The row + col index are all > 0. So just one dict is needed.

```
from collections import defaultdict

bishops = [(0, 0),
           (1, 1),
           (0, 2),
           (1, 3),
           (2, 0),
           (2, 2)]


occupied_diagonals = defaultdict(list)

for bishop in bishops:
    row, col = bishop
    occupied_diagonals[row + col].append(bishop)
    occupied_diagonals[row - col - 8].append(bishop)

in_danger = set()

for bishop_list in occupied_diagonals.values():
    if len(bishop_list) > 1:
        in_danger.update(bishop_list)

print(len(in_danger))
```

Comment: A nice answer (+1), but it could use [improvement](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/224060/100620).

Comment: @AJNeufeld, yes, lots of room for improvement.  I don't know the skill level of OP and wanted to explain it simply without a lot of things that might be new.  It could use a defaultdict.  And if you offset one of the "diagonal" indexes (e.g add -8 to the row-column) so the numbers don't overlap, it would only need one dict.  That would cut the code in half.

Comment: While I like the reduction in code, I dislike the magic number `-8`. The code will no longer work for larger (or infinite) boards. You could fix this by subtracting `max(row)+1`. Alternately, you could turn the indices into strings `f"/{row+col}"` and `fr"\{row-col}"`, adding a leading `/` for indices on one diagonal, and \ for the other. Or you could multiply the indices by 2, and then add 1 to partition by even/odd: `(row+col)*2` & `(row-col)*2+1`.  Or, you could partition by int/str with `row+col` and `str(row-col)` or by int/float by adding `+0.5`, depending on how hacky you want to be.